# Please use the PostgreSQL GUI tool useful

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I use Postgresql but no GUI tool satisfy me.

I do table creation, modification, and more, use database or table backup and restore functions.

**Are there any useful tools to provide this functionality?**

**If you are using a Mac please refer both free and paid versions.**

> PgAdmin3, Postico I tried using. HeidiSQL was used in the Windows
>   satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

[`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html) command line interface.

not `graphical` but you can learn every aspect of the database. go this way and in a future you will be more productive than with any gui tool. not hard to learn.

`psql` available on on all os - windows, linux, osx,... of course, you don't have "gui" but in a short time you will be more productive and familiar with it than from any gui interface.

just start using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html

pgadmin3 no longer maintained (pgadmin4 is at the moment mess), some lack some features from psql and you need to pay for them - psql is free and contains all features ;)

Comment: It is not the answer I want. For example, is the command terminal on a Mac?

Comment: This is not an answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin 4 is getting better with each release. Still, if you want to try a free alternative for MacOS, take a look at Postage:

https://www.workflowproducts.com/postage.html